# Adding a class to an ul that has more (or) less than 2 li's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to every ul that has more (or equal&less than) 2 li's.

Somehow I can't get it going. I either end up with a class added to all level 2 ul's or to none.

Here's the code I'm, using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countli = $('ul.level_2 li').length;
    if(countli >= 3) {
      $("ul.level_2").addClass("short");
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/gmodesignz/20dksk4y/3/

Comment: You count `li`s in **all** `ul`s at once and add class to **all** `ul`s if total count is `>= 3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Script*

```
$("ul.level_2").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('li').length >= 3
}).addClass("short");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2z7p00mk/)

Comment: Thanks! I marked the answer as the correct one since the filter function made for the most compact code.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is you are generalizing everything. Make it specific inside the closures. See the below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.level_2').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length > 2)
      $(this).addClass("short");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
ul {color: blue;}
.short {color: red;}
.large {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li class="sub">
    Long Submenu
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    Short Submenu
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also you must apply the class to the parents and not the children.

Comment: Thanks, this works...however I checked Satpal's solution as the filter solution seems to be a better approach... 

You were close second as I really apreciate your explanation along with the solution

Comment: @TheGmo Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class to `ul` elements which has a 3rd `li` child(ie has more than 2 `li`) like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.level_2').has('li:eq(2)').addClass("short");
});
```

```css
ul {
  color: blue;
}
.short {
  color: red;
}
.large {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li class="sub">
    Long Submenu
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    Short Submenu
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works...however I checked Satpal's solution as the filter solution seems to be a better approach...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul .level_2").each(function(){
        var countLi = $(this).find("li").length;
        if(countLi <= 3 ){
           $(this).find("li").addClass("short");
         }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/OsamaMohamed/wsu8xwwg/

Comment: Thanks, this works...however I checked Satpal's solution as the filter solution seems to be a better approach...